# Replace MS Word bookmark with HTML content C# .NET

Tags: c#, html, ms-word

I have MS Word template with content inside.
In the middle of the content I have a specific bookmark that I want to replace with HTML file (not the tags view, all the visual view).
What is the easiest way to do it?
I found the option to insert a file but couldn't find to insert it to a specific place instead of a bookmark.
Thanks.

Comment: Has your question been answered?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Range` object with the `InsertFile` method. For example the following code will insert a file where the bookmark is:

```
Word.Range rngBookmark = wdDoc.Bookmarks["test"].Range;
rngBookmark.InsertFile(filePath);
```